# Solving homogeneous equation with undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand how A was solved, however how does $A= 1/(\ln^2 (2)+1)$ become $y_p=2^x/(\ln^2 (2)+1)$?
[image: al]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the particular solution is $y_p=A2^x$ Then you plug this in the differential equation to find the value of the constant A. Since $A=\frac {1}{\ln^2 2 +1}$ then $$y_p=A2^x=\frac {2^x}{\ln^2 2+1}$$

$y_p$ is a function where $A$ is a constant. What we want to find is the particular function that solves the inhomogeneous equation.A didn't become $y_p$